# Get subclass length from main class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the lenght of class `class="item x"` from `class="second select visible"`
Here is the html. I have here 2 parent class with same class child but I want to get the lenght of that class from 2nd parent class.

```
<div class="first select">
    <div class="item x">text 1</div>
    <div class="item x">text 2</div>
</div>

<div class="second select visible">
    <div class="item x">text 1</div>
    <div class="item x">text 2</div>
    <div class="item x">text 2</div>
</div>
```

And here I have the code

```
setInterval(function check(optv2){
    const testexist = document.getElementsByClassName('second select visible').lenght > 0;
    var list = /* lenght of 'item x' from 'second select' */
        if (testexist == true){
            console.log(testexist);
            if(list == 2){
               /* code */   
                }else{
                    console.log("var is not 2");
            }
            /* var 4*/
             if(list == 4){
                /*code*/
                }else{
                    console.log("var is not 4");
            }
        }else{
            console.log('class not avaible');
            clearInterval();
        }
}, 30000);
```

Comment: You are writing length spelling wrong everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) you can do it like this, where it will get you the list of `item`'s in one go.

As you can see, when having many classes set on an element, you can use one, `.second`, or chain them, `.second.select.visible`, when create the CSS selector.

*Note, a class name like `x` is not valid, it should have at least 2 characters, so I used only `item`.*

- [*Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

Stack snippet

```js
//setInterval(function check(optv2){
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.second.select.visible .item');
if (list.length > 0) {
  /* var 2*/
  if (list.length == 2) {
    /* code */
  } else {
    console.log("var is not 2");
  }

  /* var 3*/
  if (list.length == 3) {
    console.log("var is 3");
  } else {
    console.log("var is not 3");
  }

  /* var 4*/
  if (list.length == 4) {
    /*code*/
  } else {
    console.log("var is not 4");
  }
} else {
  console.log('class not avaible');
  clearInterval();
}
//}, 30000);
```

```html
<div class="first select">
  <div class="item x">text 1</div>
  <div class="item x">text 2</div>
</div>

<div class="second select visible">
  <div class="item x">text 1</div>
  <div class="item x">text 2</div>
  <div class="item x">text 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can get the count by

```
document.querySelectorAll(".select.visible .item.x")
```

example here - https://jsfiddle.net/kcsL26tb/2/

Comment: An answer using that tech is given already, and as stated in the same answer, a class name shouldn't be just one character, and even if OP posted like such, you shouldn't repeat the syntax error in an answer.

Comment: @rohithayyampully If you add `.length` to the end of your code line, it would be a little more clear. What you have now, just returns a collection, not the number of elements.